# Normalirz: collect entities from nested data

Tags: javascript, redux, normalizr

How can I properly [normalize](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) big data using normalizr? I get an nested data from the api and I need to divide it by the user entities, where the data will be stored separately.

**data from api**

```
[
    {
        user: {
            email: "test@test.com"
            lastname: "User"
            name: "User"
            password: "123"
            _id: 1,
        }
        date: "2021",
        details: [
            {
                category: "admin"
                name: "superadmin"
                access: 1
            }
        ],
        _id: 'xdre24d'
    }
]
```

**schema**

```
  const userSchema = new schema.Entity('userSchema', {}, { idAttribute: '_id' });
  const users = new schema.Entity(
    'users',
    { user: new schema.Array(userSchema) },
    { idAttribute: '_id' },
  );

  const normalData = normalize(data, new schema.Array(users));
```

**how would you like to get normalizr data**

```
entities: {
  user: {
    a: {
      name: "User"
      email: "test@test.com",
        lastname: "User"
    },
    b: {
      name: "User"
      email: "test@test.com",
        lastname: "User"
    }
  }
}
```